# problem with resizing movieclip inside movieclip in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have two movieclips, one loads an image, I resize that mc and add it in a bigger movieclip which has to be resized too. My problem is that that the inner movieclip doesn't resize the way I want although I've tried many variants of the sequence of the commands. I've also taken into account something that I read that an empty mc resizes strangely but it didn't change anything.

that's the code:

```
loader_mc.x=0;
loader_mc.y=0;
cont_mc.x=1440;
cont_mc.y=0;

trace(loader_mc.width,loader_mc.width);
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderReady);
var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("0.jpg");
myLoader.load(fileRequest);

function onLoaderReady(e:Event) {
loader_mc.addChild(myLoader);
cont_mc.addChild(loader_mc);
loader_mc.height=707;
loader_mc.width=500;

cont_mc.height=1000;
cont_mc.width=1440;
}
```

[image]

red mc is the outer one but the sizes of the inner are not right it should be about one third of the outer but it's about two thirds. same with the height.

All I want is to be able to resize them independenlty. with the outter beeing bigger than the inner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is

```
cont_mc.width = 1440;  
//  set this first 

loader_mc.width = 500 * (1 / cont_mc.scaleX); 
//  loader_mc shows up at 500px on screen  

loader_mc.y = ((cont_mc.height - loader_mc.height*cont_mc.scaleY )/2) * (1 / cont_mc.scaleY);
//center loader_mc inside cont_mc
```